Why does the 2nd Ata in Ata Gibor have different Emphasis?
Why does the 2nd "Ata" in Ata Gibor have the emphasis on the first syllable (AH-ta),
unlike the 1st "Ata" which is pronounced as normal (ah-TA)?


What Siddur are you looking at?

@DoubleAA ArtScroll, but I've definitely seen it also in other Siddurim

It is one of the pausal clauses.

@YDJ Thanks, wasn't sure

@YDJ Thus the difference between a cat and a comma: the former has its paws before its claws, the latter has its clause before its pause.

Questions like this make me realize how little I know about the siddur

I believe I've seen a consistent pattern in the syllable accent where אתה comes after the descriptor vs before, sort of like saying "____ are you" vs "you are ____".

@YDJ Half pause. A full pause would yield אָֽתָּה (in biblical hebrew)

Many siddurim do not create a pause after אתה. That is primarily view of Artscroll. Perhaps, there is a difference of opinion regarding whether one should say מחיה מתים אתה together or אתה רב להושיע together.

There's an answer to this that can be found in Emes L'Yaakov Al HaTorah, p. מ״ו-מ״ז (h/t to user J. W. Tanner for making we aware of this in the answer to this question.)
It's a matter of the structure of the passuk, and how the words are broken up. He actually says, though this is not a common practice, that when you say Morid HaTal the second "Ata" would be Ah-TAH, on the second half of the word, even though when you say Mashiv HaRuach or nothing at all there (the Ashkenazi minhag in Chutz La'aretz during the summer) it is pronounced AH-tah, as most siddurim indicate.
Here's why, according to him. A good indicator of how exactly to break up the passuk is what the trop is/would be. Though admittedly, I don't know how he knew this (perhaps beyond the scope of the question too) the trop over those words in Shmoneh Esrei without any insertion there would be
 and with Mashiv HaRuach it would be similar 
whereas with Morid HaTal it would be .
According to the Minchas Shai, if the word "ata" is a sof passuk, esnachta, or a zakeif katon (like this one), the emphasis moves from the end of the word to the beginning of the word. Any other note, it remains at the end of the word.

"I don't know how he knew this" He made it up. He's using it to demonstrate where he thinks the breaks ought be, not as proof that these are where the breaks are

Your last paragraph might represent the general case, but not all cases. See eg Deut 7:6 on the one hand, and Gen 32:18 on the other.

@magicker72 True and a very valid point. Would be worth looking into when it does and doesn't change the accentage
